# Shiny - All sub-lists in "choices" must be named?

Tags: r, shiny

I want to create a select options like this below,

```
<select id="species">
  <option value="1">A</option>
  <option value="2">B</option>
  <option value="3">C</option>
</select>
```

So I use data frame to create a table that stores the data,

```
# Create the species table for select input.
title <- c('A', 'B', 'C')
code <- c('1', '2', '3')
species <- data.frame(title, code)

# Set choices of title and code for select input.
choicesSpecies <- setNames(species$code, species$title)
```

Shiny's ui.R,

```
selectInput(inputId = "species",
                  label = "Species:",
                  choices = choicesSpecies),
```

I get this error,

```
Error in (function (choice, name)  : 
  All sub-lists in "choices" must be named.
```

What does it mean? How can I fix it to get the result that I need?

Comment: could you try using `choices=species$code`, and then use a `switch` statement to get the equivalent code?

Comment: Does the error occur as well when you set the names this way (I never got errors when using this approach): choicesSpecies <- species$code; names(choicesSpecies) <- species$title

Comment: thanks guys. but none of the suggestions work I am afraid...

Answer (score 9):

Having the `code` column as a factor in your data frame seems to be the issue, maybe try:

```
choicesSpecies <- setNames(as.numeric(species$code), species$title)
```

Or:

```
#create the named list
title <- c('A', 'B', 'C')
code <- c('1', '2', '3')
names(code) <- title
```

In your `ui.R`:

```
selectInput(inputId = "species",
                label = "Species:",
                choices = code)
```

Comment: Thanks NicE. It works with `choicesSpecies <- setNames(as.numeric(species$code), species$title)` but I get the same error if I have this data instead in my code var - `code <- c('a', 'b', 'c')`...

Answer (score 2):

In response to your comment (not enough rep to reply) regarding:

```
code <- c('a','b','c')
```

You need to change them to characters in the same way you were changing them to numeric.
e.g.

```
choicesSpecies <- setNames(as.character(species$code), species$title)
```