# Using quote() and substitute() for conditions within a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, conditional-statements, subset, quote

I'm trying to use quote/substitute as a method to apply a condition in shiny. I'm not very familiar with either quote/substitute or shiny - so it is definitely possible that I'm not going about this problem in the right way.

I've created a simple example below that I illustrates the problem I get.

```
#Create test dataframe
test<-data.frame(x=c(0:10), y=c(rep(1,5),rep(2,6)), z=c("A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C","C","C","C"))

#example of what I would like to do outside shiny app 
test[test$x > 5,]

#or using quote and eval 
test[eval(quote(test$x > 5)),]
```

All of the above code works. But now lets say I want to apply it within a shiny app (and allow the user to choose the condition):

```
#create simple shiny app
require(shiny)


# Server
server <- function(input, output) {


  # subset of nodes
    df <- reactive({

        #eliminate certain observations 
        x <- test[eval(input$condition),]

    })

    output$table <- renderTable({
        df <- df()


    })


}



# UI 
ui <- fluidPage(

radioButtons("conditon", "Condition", choices = c("cond_1" = substitute(test$x > 5), "cond_2" = substitute(test$x<5))),

tableOutput("table")


)


# Create app 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

But this gives the error "All sub-lists in "choices" must be names"). I'm not sure how to interpret this, and so am stuck. I looked at the answers in [Shiny - All sub-lists in "choices" must be named?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30022732/shiny-all-sub-lists-in-choices-must-be-named) but did not find them helpful.

Would appreciate a way to solve this, or suggestions of a better approach (though note that I can't create the subsets ahead of time, as for my more complex actual example this creates issues).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick fix could be to wrap with `deparse` and then use `eval(parse`.  It is not entirely clear why the input needs to be expressions.  If this is just for subsetting, there are easier ways to accomplish the same

```
library(shiny)
```

-ui

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  radioButtons("conditon", "Condition", 
                  choices = list(cond_1 = deparse(substitute(test$x > 5)),
                                 cond_2 = deparse(substitute(test$x<5))),
            selected = deparse(substitute(test$x > 5)) ),

   tableOutput("table")

  )
```

-server

```
server <- function(input, output) {

  # subset of nodes
  df <- reactive({

    #eliminate certain observations 
     test[eval(parse(text=input$conditon)),, drop = FALSE]


  })

  output$table <- renderTable({
     df()


  })


}
```

-Create app

```
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

-output

[image]

[image]

Comment: I've copied your code exactly and I encounter the error "invalid subscript type 'list'". Any idea why it runs for you but not for me?

Comment: @Robert.S  I am using `shiny_1.0.3` if that matters

Comment: I'm also using shiny_1.0.3.

Comment: In trying to sort this out I get some other weird results. 

For example, I tried adding a selected argument to the radioButtons condition variable:

`radioButtons("conditon", "Condition", 
               choices = list(cond_1 = deparse(substitute(test$x > 5)),
                              cond_2 = deparse(substitute(test$x<5))), selected = deparse(substitute(test$x > 5))),` 

But I then get the error `Selected argument must be of length 1`. However when I run `length(deparse(substitute(test$x > 5)))` I get the result `1`.

Comment: @Robert.S  For me, it is working fine, `ui <- fluidPage(
  radioButtons("conditon", "Condition", choices = list(cond_1 = deparse(substitute(test$x > 5)),
                                                       cond_2 = deparse(substitute(test$x<5))),
                              selected = deparse(substitute(test$x > 5)) ),
  
  tableOutput("table")
  
  
)`

Comment: I figured out (sort of) what the issue is. I had been pressing the "Run App" button at the top of R studio to do this - which produces errors. If I just run it directly by selecting the code and hitting CTRL + ENTER it works. 

Any insight as to why that is? Regardless, thanks for your help, I will accept your answer.

Comment: @Robert.S  Not sure whether any version difference of Rstudio changes it